# we are loading javascript from .cache.html file, then why we cant download it from .js?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I saw the following sentences in developers.google.com while studying gwt.

```
"The "`cache`" files contain your application's logic. If you were to look inside a 
`.nocache.html` file, you would see that it is JavaScript code wrapped in a thin HTML
 wrapper.You might wonder why the `GWT` Compiler doesn't simply emit it as a JavaScript .js 
file. The reason for this is that certain browsers do not correctly handle compression of 
pure-JavaScript files in some circumstances. This would effectively mean that users 
unfortunate enough to be using such a browser would download the `.js` file uncompressed. "
```

we are loading `javascript` from .cache.html file, 
then why we cant download it from .js? i think now all browsers supporting `javascript`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement quoted seems to have explained it quite clearly: *"certain browsers do not correctly handle compression of pure-JavaScript files in some circumstances"*. It's **not** about supporting JavaScript, it's about supporting the compression of JavaScript files.

Comment: .cache.html file also have javascript, so it is not compressed? then why it storing compressed javascript in .js file?

Comment: Browsers treat files with .js and .html extensions a bit differently.

Comment: It's not about storing compressed JS in the files, in the sense of minified and obfuscated, but about caching (in the sense of an HTTP cache) the files when sent by the server with GZip or Deflate compression applied.