# .cache.html file also have javascript, so it is not compressed? then why it storing compressed javascript in .js file?

Tags: gwt

In GWT, JavaScript code wrapped in .cache.html files. is it is not compressed? or only .js files are compressed?

Comment: Is this duplicate of the question you raised earlier at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560137/we-are-loading-javascript-from-cache-html-file-then-why-we-cant-download-it-fr

Comment: I know it's not always easy to express yourself in a foreign language but could you please edit your question to at least make it understandable?

Comment: not duplicate question, i asked that .cache.html file has javascript is it is compressed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to pretty old documentation. GWT is now 2.5 and not 1.6 .
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuide

Also ensure that you have set GWT style compiler option to "OBF"

Comment: sir, Will you give link of new documentation?